# ACE OLEDB 12.0 - Excel Data Sources

Tags: sql, excel, oledb

I am using the ACE OLEDB 12.0 provider with Excel data sources. My code is in C#.
Am I correct in believing that:

1. Multiple SQL statements are NOT supported?
2. There is no way of including comments within SQL statements?

Thanks for sharing your insight.

Comment: Please show working example of needs as this is too broad. Why comment in SQL and not in application layer? Iterative statements can be run. The Jet/ACE SQL engine used for Excel data sources via ADO is like any other RDMS with its particular SQL dialect.

Comment: This response does not help. Comments in SQL statements are required: data tier comments can be held in the SQL. I know that SQL Server providers allow in-line comments in and multiple statements. Each provider has its own dialect - Google does not come up with anything on my two points; hence my post.